# How to draw molecular in OPENGL ES 2 Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm a new in OpenGL ES 2. I have read some topic about OpenGL ES on Android and i can draw some of basic geometry : triangle, square,...Now I'm going to draw molecular such as: H2O

[H2O](http://i41.tinypic.com/99lavk.png)

But i don't know how to implement it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL by itself can only draw points, lines and triangles. Every other shape must be approximated using those.

A sphere can be approximated by either using a rings/segment or a recursively subdivided polytope. rings/segments is easier to implement.

Cylinders are just a bunch of pairs of triangles, arranged in a high face count prism.

Drawing a stick figure molecule consists of drawing the atoms as spheres and connecting them by cylinders.

I suggest you follow these steps:

- learn how to draw simple triangles
- learn how to draw using triangles approximations of

  - spheres
  - cylinders
- learn how to work with vectors and transformations so that you can move your objects in space

Then try to figure out how to combine those things to gain what you want.

Comment: Thank for your suggesion. I can do the first and the second steps but the third steps i don't know do it. I can draw spheres, i can draw cylinders but i don't known how to move them in spate to create molecular. How objects move in space?

Comment: @SơnNguyễn: For the old fixed function pipeline, this is one of the best tutorials on the subject there is: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html – for the modern OpenGL programmable pipeline I recommend you work through the tutorials of Nicol Bolas: http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut

Comment: @SơnNguyễn - Additionally, you might be able to pick through the code for my iOS molecular modeler (available here: http://sunsetlakesoftware.com/molecules ) and extract the OpenGL ES I use for rendering that. I describe the process in a broader fashion here: http://sunsetlakesoftware.com/2011/05/08/enhancing-molecules-using-opengl-es-20